# Specialisations in use case diagrams

Tags: uml, use-case, specialization, use-case-diagram

I am working on a use case diagram and I was wondering if this is a correct use of a Specialized use case. Here I have Create which has 3 different specialisations. What I am trying to demonstrate here is that the user can create a Team, Project or a Board. I feel this might not be the correct use of specialisation. Would it make more sense to split these into "Create Team", "Create project" etc...?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML a use case is a classifier and can be specialized.  From a notation point of view this is correct.  However, you shoud reconsider the wording of the names, since the specialized use case may be used or reused independently of their generalization.

What about: `Create item`, `Create project`, `Create team`, `Create board` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This implementation with some word changing would be okay? Would a use case with extension points make more sense or is the way that I have done it good to demonstrate the action being carried out which is "Create". I was also looking to implement "Edit" & "Delete". Would it be better to use case with extension points or would you recommend using specialisations for Create, Edit, Delete?

Comment: @Krellex I'd tend to prefer specialization in your example: extension is for adding possibly optional sub-goals, but here the main use case (delete item) would not make any sense without the subgoals.